# Статическая сборка проекта в Qt4 Creator для Windows

Tags: windows, qt, c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как собрать проект Qt Creator под Windows, чтобы скомпилированная exe не требовала никаких библиотек.

Answer (score 2):

Скажу честно, у меня, когда пробовал, так и не получилось собрать статическую сборку, но хорошо описано [здесь](http://www.prog.org.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%A1%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)